# Brokerage Account and Non-Domiciled Status in UK

Tags: investing, united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax, tax-residency

I have recently moved to the UK and want to move my IBKR Ireland account that was linked to my previous French residence status. The UK allows those with non-UK domicile to keep their worldwide income tax free as long as those are not brought into the UK.

My question is what does it imply for non UK capital gains that are held in UK interactive brokers? Just because they are gains from non-UK entities, would they be considered non-UK income even if held by a UK branch of the brokerage? If so what are the other options for me to keep my capital gains from non-UK stocks tax free based on the domicile law?